# Why did four EU countries break the EU consensus over the US embassy in Jerusalem?

Tags: european-union, israel, austria, jerusalem, country-neutrality

[This article](https://www.timesofisrael.com/four-eu-envoys-to-attend-israeli-event-feting-us-embassy-move/) argues about four EU countries sending ambassadors to attend the official inauguration of the US embassy in Jerusalem:

> Breaking with European consensus, the ambassadors of four EU countries
> are set to attend a reception Sunday at the Foreign Ministry in honor
> of the official inauguration of the US embassy in Jerusalem this week.
>
> The Foreign Ministry invited 86 foreign ambassadors stationed in
> Israel to the event, a day before the official move. About 40 of them
> announced their participation, Foreign Ministry spokesperson Emmanuel
> Nahshon said Saturday, including Austria, Czech Republic, Romania, and
> Hungary.
>
> (..)
>
> Most European countries have slammed US President Donald
> Trump’s move as not in line with international consensus, preferring
> to wait on recognizing the city until the status of Jerusalem is
> finalized in talks with the Palestinians.

So the EU seems reserved when it comes to this very sensitive matter, probably because [it favors two state solution](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/commissioners/2014-2019/hahn/announcements/eu-releases-eu212-million-support-palestinian-people_en):

> Commissioner for Neighbourhood and Enlargement Negotiations, Johannes
> Hahn, commented: “The EU remains committed to the two-state solution
> and will therefore continue to support the Palestinian Authority in
> its state-building efforts and in delivering basic social services.
> Our support remains the quickest and most effective way to deliver
> funding to the Palestinians, including those living in Gaza, in a
> moment of severe difficulties”.

**Question:** Why did the four countries break the EU consensus over the
US embassy in Jerusalem?

For Romania I assume it is related to the [US-Romania Strategic Partnership](https://ro.usembassy.gov/20-years-strategic-partnership/). I find Austria's case particularly interesting due to its [neutrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_country).

Comment: Isn't Austria's newly elected leader pro-Israel far more than EU consensus in general? This seems very right up his alley politically.

Comment: None of these countries move their embassy. So it is anything but usual media propaganda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Austrian ministry for foreign affairs stated, that the participation was out of courtesy, and does not imply any change in Austria's official position.

Source: [Article in Austrian newspaper "Die Presse"](https://diepresse.com/home/ausland/aussenpolitik/5430434/Aus-Protest_Palaestina-zieht-Botschafter-aus-Oesterreich-ab)